# chess program wilhelm

Tags: software, endgame, tablebases

I still search an executable file of the chess program wilhelm. It is not only a chess
 endgame database, you can fix pieces to be on concrete squares and check all such position
 to get a statistic how many positions are won/draw/lost.

I downloaded a version long ago, but it did not work. I could not find any results.

Does anyone know if there is an executable file ? And if yes, does it also consider
 DTC or DTZ - metrics ?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a link with informations you can get on chess program Wilhelm.

http://web.archive.org/web/20081208015339/http://www.geocities.com/rba_schach2000/overview_english.htm

Unfortunately, this chess program by Rafael B. Andrist stopped being developped in 2006.

Comment: Did you check if it works ?

Comment: @Peter Tanj has no responsibility for checking for you. He did give you a very useful link, it's your job to check it.